# Maas Check Power State - Error: Unknown power_type 'ether_wake'

Tags: server, power-management, maas

I have `etherwake` installed and Maas can use it to power on the nodes, but it can't shut them down and the "Check power state" button yields the error: `Error: Unknown power_type 'ether_wake'.`
Am I missing something? Should the power type be different to allow for complete control of nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the etherwake man page: "etherwake is a program that generates and transmits a Wake-On-LAN (WOL) "Magic Packet", used for restarting machines that have been soft-powered-down (ACPI D3-warm state).

MAAS supports the wake-on-Lan power type. You can add a node in MAAS and choose 'Wake-on-Lan' from the power type drop down menu, and that will give you the same power on capability.

Wake-on-lan only powers on nodes, it does not power off nodes (this the reason for the error). It's a limitation on this power control. Using other power types, such as IPMI, Virsh, etc., will allow you to power on and off nodes.

Comment: Thank you @catbus. I realised this later on, but forgot to update the question.